# Let an app do something after a certain time

Tags: android, timer

I'm currently developing an app that I want to let do things (like opening activities) after a certain time, like for example five seconds.

What code do I Need for that?

Comment: What code do you _have_?

Comment: Use a CountDownTimer.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.  Especially since there are a couple of wrong answers!  H8rs gotta h8... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        rsong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.party);
        rsong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.myapp.MENU");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        };
        timer.start();
}
```

Try this.

Here intent activity redirects you to the new layout where you want to transfer.

Also you will need to modify **"Androidmanfiest.xml"**.

Intent activity could be done couple of different ways.

So first try this with thread.

Comment: This code has some crazy bugs.  If you rotate the screen while the Activity is visible, there will be multiple Threads firing intents, and you will leak an Activity's worth of memory

Answer (score 1):

You need the AlarmManager:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, YourServiceOrBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi
        = PendingIntent.getService(this, INTENT_ID, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE))
        .setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + 100,
            POLL_INTERVAL,
            pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler and create a different thread with a delay. Suppose you want to launch an intent after 4 seconds, use this:

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }, 4000);
```